# Python pass object function and reference funciton variables

Tags: python, opengl

Say I am working with OpenGL in python.

Often times you make a call such as

```
glutDisplayFunc(display)
```

where display is a function that you have written.

What if I have a class

```
class foo:
    #self.x=5
    def display(self, maybe some other variables):
        #run some code
        print("Hooray!, X is:", self.x)
```

and I want to pass that display function and have it print "Hooray!, X is: 5"

Would I pass it as

```
h = foo()
glutDisplayFunc(h.display)
```

Could this work?

Comment: So, then just try it.

Comment: You should add an `__init__` function, though, in order to make `self.x` known.

Comment: Usually class names are in CamelCase and function names in snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the function like that:

```
h = foo()
glutDisplayFunc(h.display)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your class:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 5
  def display(self):
    print("hooray {}".format(self.x))
```

And this your `glut_display_func()`:

```
def glut_display_func(func):
  func()
```

You can do this:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.display()

glut_display_func(foo.display)
```

and get the same result:

```
hooray 5
hooray 5
```